# ANDROID: Soft keyboard doesn't work properly

Tags: android, window-soft-input-mode

I had a problem with my layout, when the softkeyboard was visible, page scroll did not working.I searched through net and I find out using

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

solves the problem, and it did. However it caused some other problems. Now when I choose an edittext to type, the soft input covers the edittext and I can't see what I'm typing.

So I decided to get ride of that and I removed it from my manifest. But it didn't come back to previous state. It still works like the way it worked with adjustResize. (I cleaned and build project several times, I restarted my pc and cellphone couple times, I test it in other cellphones,...).
Also, when Soft keyboard is open, and I touch to open the navigation drawer menu, the menu opens under keyboard too!!!

I can't figure out what did happened!

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically remove keyboard from screen by toggling it off. Please try below and call it after you are done with your edittext. It will remove keyboard from screen.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
              Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(YOUREDITTEXT.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

As you stated, that is for closing soft keyboard, also for handling your issue, you need to have a scroll layout as your parent layout, with using

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

like you already did. After applying those, you will have no issue.

Comment: Yhansk for answering my question, however this code just make the soft keyboard hidden after typing, my problem is when I touch edittext, the keyboard comes over edittext, it covers edittext.